# Changing or adding existing members to another member group

Tags: members, solspace-user, member-management

Is there a way to move an existing member from one member group to another? If so, how can this be done?

Also, is it possible to have one member belong to multiple groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the member group from Member Administration --> Member Preferences pane in the user profile page.

If you want a user to be part of multiple member groups, you can use any Module that threats members as entries, such as
[Solspace User](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/user)
or [Zoovisitor](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor)

Comment: @Miksama Solspace User and Zoovisitor are great add ons, but they do not manage **access permissions** for multiple group memberships. To manage member permissions based on multiple group memberships, you will need a module called  [HooBlong](http://debeer.com)

Comment: A note about Solspace User: it does not create a channel entry for the member (although you can always link an entry with a member through the author_id, for example). Solspace User uses the native EE member module, and stores data in the same places as the native EE member module. However, with User templating is simpler than EE's member templating.